# Cannot add a reference to 'MathNet.Numerics' - NuGet package installation fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I use Visual Studio 2015 and can't get it install the 'MathNet.Numerics' NuGet package using "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution".

I try to install "Latest stable 4.9.0".

Target framework is ".NET Framework 4.6.1".

When I'm trying to solve the problem through "Package Manager Console", I get the same result.

Here are the details:

Output:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' with respect to project 'SRTP_Pro1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0'
Adding package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' to folder 'D:\Learning\C++\SRTP_Pro1\packages'
Added package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' to folder 'D:\Learning\C++\SRTP_Pro1\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' does not exist in project 'SRTP_Pro1'
Removing package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' from folder 'D:\Learning\C++\SRTP_Pro1\packages'
Removed package 'MathNet.Numerics.4.9.0' from folder 'D:\Learning\C++\SRTP_Pro1\packages'
Failed to add reference to 'MathNet.Numerics'.
========== Finished ==========
```

Error window only displays this:

```
Failed to add reference to 'MathNet.Numerics'.
```

Can you think of why? Or how can I diagnose further?

Emmm, after I ran setup program to fix it, failure just disapeared.
So I think it might be a bug.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Please spend more time on your questions, and give us the full details. How can we possibly help right now when all you have told us is "it doesn't work"? Give us more details and we can help much more quickly.

Comment: What version of MathNet are you trying to add?

Comment: What is the .Net version of your project?

Comment: Don't post images of text, please. I can't copy/paste that into google translate

Comment: This is an English speaking site I'm afraid. Going to vote to close this question now.

Comment: My FrameWork is .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

It is Support subject:
Example Latest Version of MathNet.Numerics supports .Net Framework 4.0 or higher and .Net Standard 1.3 or higher

So you may try installing **One of the Previous Versions** of the NuGet based on your current Framework version

Comment: This might be the answer, but without further information from the question asker, it's just a guess. We generally discourage answers like that.

Comment: And now we see they are using .NET Framework 4.6.1 which makes this answer wrong. This is why we wait for good quality questions :)